# Merge two dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

for a long time can't resolve smth looking like as very simple matter... I want merge a two dimensional arrays.
The example:

```
$arr1 = {
  [532] =
  {
    [0] = "11"
    [1] = "12"
  }
  [273] =
  {
    [0] = "99"
  }
}
$arr2 = {
  [532] =
  {
    [0] = "11"
    [1] = "13"
  }
}
```

And the result of merging should be, a map on common keys, exactly like that array:

```
$result = {
  [532] =
  {
     [0] =
     {      
        [0] = "11"
        [1] = "12"
     }
     [1] =
     {
        [0] = "11"
        [1] = "13"
     }
  }
  [273]
     [0] =
     {      
        [0] = "99"
     }
     [1] =
     {

     }
}
```

I try sometihng like that:

```
    $result = $arr1;
    foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key] = isset($result[$key]) ? array_merge([$result[$key]], [$value]) : [$value];
    }
```

But it doesnt work if $arr2 is empty :(

Comment: What do you mean by `if $arr2 is empty`. Why to merge if you don't have second array ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably something like this

```
 $arr1 = {
      [532] =
      {
        [0] = "11"
        [1] = "12"
      }
      [273] =
      {
        [0] = "99"
      }
    }
    $arr2 = {
      [532] =
      {
        [0] = "11"
        [1] = "13"
      }
    }

   $newarray = array();
   foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
      $cu = $arr1[$key];

      $newarray[$key][] = $cu;

      if(!isset($arr2[$key])) {
            $newarray[$key][] = array();
       }
       else {
         $newarray[$key][] = $arr2[$key];
       }
   }

foreach ($arr2 as $key => $value) {
          if(!isset($newarray[$key])) {
             $newarray[$key][] = $arr2[$key]; 
          }
       }
```

Comment: Arg, your right - think I've got it now - bit tricky without the f5 button!

Comment: See where your going with it - ok

Comment: Ok, but what if the first array will be empty? I always want to get array with structure like in the example

Comment: Then do another foreach loop to stick in any of the ones missing.

Comment: I mean.. Arrays may look the other way around

Comment: Like that! ok is everyone happy?

Answer (score 1):

For the second array checking, you need to use `isset()` either array set or not:

**Example:**

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('532'=>array('11','12'),'273'=>array('99'));
$arr2 = array('532'=>array('11','13'));

$newArr = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
   if(isset($arr2[$key])){
      $newArr[$key][] = $value;
      $newArr[$key][] = $arr2[$key];
   }
   else{
      $newArr[$key] = $value;
   }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [532] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                    [1] => 12
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                    [1] => 13
                )

        )

    [273] => Array
        (
            [0] => 99
        )

)
```

Further more, if you want to merge both same index than you can use `array_merge()` some thing like that:

```
<?php
$arr1 = array('532'=>array('11','12'),'273'=>array('99'));
$arr2 = array('532'=>array('11','13'));

$newArr = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
   if(isset($arr2[$key])){
      $newArr[$key][] = array_merge($value,$arr2[$key]);      
   }
   else{
      $newArr[$key] = $value;
   }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [532] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11
                    [1] => 12
                    [2] => 11
                    [3] => 13
                )

        )

    [273] => Array
        (
            [0] => 99
        )

)
```

Note that, *ist script*, will give you result as you need with unique index.
*Second script* will give you all values in one single array.